# write in event log in vb.net

Tags: sharepoint, event-log, access-denied

I've developped a sharepoint 2007 feature in vb.net.
Inside, have an application page and in onload method, i want to write message in event log

```
Dim cs As String = "TESTLOG"
    Dim elog As New EventLog()
    Dim sourceExist As Boolean

    Try
        sourceExist = EventLog.SourceExists(cs)
    Catch ex As Exception
        sourceExist = False
    End Try

    If Not sourceExist Then
        Dim ev As New EventLogPermission(EventLogPermissionAccess.Administer, ".")
        ev.PermitOnly()
        EventLog.CreateEventSource(cs, "TESTLOG")
    End If
    elog.Source = cs
    elog.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    EventLog.WriteEntry(cs, message, EventLogEntryType.[Error])
```

The source is correctly created but when i try to write, i've an access denied.
I go to registry to set permission full control at everyone but still have the message.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   SYSTEM
      CurrentControlSet
         Services
            Eventlog
               Application

How can i write message in event log?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make sure the user account that is running the website has full access to the event log.  See if the following link is of any help.

[KB2028427](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028427?wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: i set permission full control to the application pool user and everyone. My source doesn't have CustomSD key, i have to add it? with wich value for everyone for testing

Answer (score 0):

I found opening the program I was running the script from as an 'administrator' let me create the log in Event Viewer.

Also:

```
If Not sourceExist Then
    Dim ev As New EventLogPermission(EventLogPermissionAccess.Administer, ".")
    ev.PermitOnly()
    EventLog.CreateEventSource(cs, "TESTLOG")
End If
```

Will mean you have to set up ID messages, or get this at the top of your message.

(The description for Event ID 51001 from source Test cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.)

To be simple, do this instead:

```
If Not sourceExist Then
    EventLog.CreateEventSource(sourceName, logName)
End If
```

This will stop the message above from occuring - instead only showing the message you sent to the EventLog.